# Insert blanks into output file pointer (ofp)

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

The objective of this script is to take an incoming csv file, read it with a DictReader, 
take the keys that were read, see if they match any of the pre-designated values in the fieldMap dictionary, and if they do match, append those keys to my hdrlist. Then, write the header list to an outputted file call ofp.

This issue that I am having is that when I don't a key that matches one of the pre-designated values in the fieldMap, I need to insert a blank (' ').

I've tried appending blank values to the hdrlist in an else statement and having a blank key value pair in my fieldMap dictionary:

```
if row.has_key(ft_test):
    hdrlist.append(ft_test)
else:
    hdrlist.append('')


'':[''] #blank key:value pair
```

,but then my:

```
if hdrlen != len(hdrlist)-1:
    print "Cannot Cannot find a key for %s in file %s" % (ft,fn)"
```

error handling statement returns more print statements than I think it should, and I'm not sure as to why.

If anyone can shed some light as to how to insert blank into my ofp.write(fmtstring), it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if anyone could shed some light as to why i get more print statement than I think I should with the above else statement, it would be greatly appreciated as well.

My whole script is below, and if there is any other info needed to help me with this code, I will gladly provide it.

Here is a sample of an input file that would produce to many print statements.

input_file.csv = {'cust_no':1, 'streetaddr':'2103 Union Ave','address2':' ','city':'Chicago'}

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, csv, glob

fieldMap = {'zipcode':['Zip5', 'zip9','zipcode','ZIP','zip_code','zip','ZIPCODE'],
        'firstname':['firstname','FIRSTNAME'],
        'lastname':['lastname','LASTNAME'],
        'cust_no':['cust_no','CUST_NO'],
        'user_name':['user_name','USER_NAME'],
        'status':['status','STATUS'],
        'cancel_date':['cancel_date','CANCEL_DATE'],
        'reject_date':['REJECT_DATE','reject_date'],
        'streetaddr':['streetaddr','STREETADDR','ADDRESS','address'],
        'streetno':['streetno','STREETNO'],
        'streetnm':['streetnm','STREETNM'],
        'suffix':['suffix','SUFFIX'], #suffix of street name: dr, ave, st
        'city':['city','CITY'],
        'state':['state','STATE'],
        'phone_home':['phone_home','PHONE_HOME'],
        'email':['email','EMAIL'],
        '':['']
        }


def readFile(fn,ofp):
    count = 0
    CSVreader = csv.DictReader(open(fn,'rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in CSVreader:
        count+= 1
        if count == 1:
            hdrlist = []
            for ft in fieldMap.keys():
                hdrlen = len(hdrlist)
                for ft_test in fieldMap[ft]:
                    if row.has_key(ft_test):
                        hdrlist.append(ft_test)
                if hdrlen != len(hdrlist)-1:
                    print "Cannot find a key for %s in file %s" % (ft,fn)


        if len(hdrlist) != 16:
            print "Another error. Not all header's have been assigned new values."
        if count < 5:
            x=len(hdrlist)
            fmtstring = "%s\t" * len(hdrlist) % tuple(row[x] for x in hdrlist)
            ofp.write(fmtstring)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    filenames = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
    ofp = sys.stdout
    ofp.write("zipcode\tfirstname\tlastname\tcust_no\tuser_name\tstatus\t"
              "cancel_date\treject_date\tstreetaddr\tstreetno\tstreetnm\t"
              "suffix\tcity\tstate\tphone_home\temail")

    for filename in filenames:
        readFile(filename,ofp)
```

Sample data:

```
cust_no,status,streetaddr,address2,city,state,zipcode,billaddr,servaddr,title,latitude,longitude,custsize,telemarket,dirmail,nocredhold,email,phone_home,phone_work,phone_fax,phone_page,phone_cell,phone_othr,taxrate1,taxrate2,taxrate3,taxtot,company,firstname,lastname,user_name,dpbc,container,seq,paytype_am,paytype_di,paytype_mc,paytype_vi
0,0,'123 fake st.',,'chicago','il',60185,'123 billaddr st.','123 servaddr st.','mr.',43.123,54.234 ,2000,'TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','email@email.com',(666)555-6666,,,,,,,,,,,'bob','smith','bob smith',,,,'TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE'
0,0,'123 fake st.','','chicago','il',60185,'123 billaddr st.','123 servaddr st.','mr.',43.123,54.234 ,2000,'TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','email@email.com',(666)555-6666,'','','','','','','','','','','bob','smith','bob smith','','','','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE'
```

Comment: Can you provide at least one input file that's producing too many print statements?

Comment: What you added looks like the value of `row` in your `for row in CSVreader:` loop. What I meant were one or more actual lines of data from the file. You can change it a bit to protect privacy. It would be useful to also include the very first line which is what defines the field names in a csv file.

Comment: Its hard to make it format like a table, but my column headers are: zipcode, firstname, lastname, cust_no, user_name, status, cancel_date, reject_date, streetaddr, streetno, streetnm, suffix, city, state, phone_home, email. Underneath each column header is many rows of the appropriate kind of data.

Comment: Can't you just copy one or two problem lines from the csv file and paste them into your question? I'd like some real data to test with. BTW, the column header are what determine the keys that the `csv.DictReader` might return in each row dictionary, so it seems somewhat inefficient (and complicated) to do all the redundant checking that you do for each row.

Comment: If i copy all of the rows it's impossible to format it as a table, but I've copies 5 columns with fake data inside it.

Comment: You don't have to format it as a table, just indent each line by 4 spaces like you do code. What you pasted doesn't look like comma delimited csv data. I would like some real data that will reproduce your problem -- something _I_ can just copy/paste into an input file for the script to read.

Comment: You use `delimiter=','` to create the `csv.DictReader` yet your csv data sample isn't comma delimited.

Comment: Sorry. It is now comma delimited

Comment: OK, that appears to be good enough -- at least I think I'm finally seeing the problem described.

Comment: I think i need to use a .get(ft) from what I've looked up

Comment: Assuming you find the right number of matching items for `hdrlist` in the header row, what do you plan on doing with it to each of the remaining rows of the csv file being read? In other words, what else does `readFile()` do?

Comment: the readFile() will insert the data underneath the designated column header or dictionary key row by row (at least that what I think and want it to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a `hdrlist` of the recognized field names in the csv file being processed, you can create it by comparing the values in the `DictReader.fieldnames` attribute to the contents of `fieldMap` immediately after creating the `DictReader` because doing so with a `filenames` argument will automatically read in the header row of the file.

I also changed your `fieldMap` dictionary into an `OrderedDict` so it would preserve the order of the keys.

```
import glob
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import sys

fieldMap = OrderedDict([
    ('zipcode', ['zipcode', 'ZIPCODE', 'Zip5', 'zip9', 'ZIP', 'zip_code', 'zip']),
    ('firstname', ['firstname', 'FIRSTNAME']),
    ('lastname', ['lastname', 'LASTNAME']),
    ('cust_no', ['cust_no', 'CUST_NO']),
    ('user_name', ['user_name', 'USER_NAME']),
    ('status', ['status', 'STATUS']),
    ('cancel_date', ['cancel_date', 'CANCEL_DATE']),
    ('reject_date', ['reject_date', 'REJECT_DATE']),
    ('streetaddr', ['streetaddr', 'STREETADDR', 'ADDRESS', 'address']),
    ('streetno', ['streetno', 'STREETNO']),
    ('streetnm', ['streetnm', 'STREETNM']),
    ('suffix', ['suffix', 'SUFFIX']),  # suffix of street name: dr, ave, st
    ('city', ['city', 'CITY']),
    ('state', ['state', 'STATE']),
    ('phone_home', ['phone_home',' PHONE_HOME']),
    ('email', ['email', 'EMAIL']),
])

def readFile(fn,ofp):
    with open(fn, 'rb') as csvfile:
        # the following reads the header line into csvReader.fieldnames
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
        # create a list of recognized fieldnames in the csv file
        hdrlist = []
        for ft in fieldMap:
            for ft_test in fieldMap[ft]:
                if ft_test in csvReader.fieldnames:
                    hdrlist.append(ft_test)
                    break
            else:
                hdrlist.append(None)  # placeholder (could  also be '')
        hdrlen = len(hdrlist)
        ofp.write('hdrlist: {}\n'.format(hdrlist))
        if hdrlen != len(fieldMap):
            print "Note that not all field names were present in file."

        ofp.write("\t".join(fieldMap) + '\n')
        for row in csvReader:
            fmtstring = "%s\t" * hdrlen % tuple(
                row[field] if field else 'NA' for field in hdrlist)
            ofp.write(fmtstring+'\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'ofp_input.csv']  # hardcode for testing
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Error:  Filename argument missing!"
        sys.exit(-1)
    filenames = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
    ofp = sys.stdout
    for filename in filenames:
        readFile(filename, ofp)
```

Comment: No worries. I understand. I changed the CSV data. My apologies for making it like a table before. I should of just put comma in between the data. My mistake. Sorry. The data is now comma delimited with no spaces in between.

Comment: Does the data now look like the sort of data in the csv files? If not, I can change it.

Comment: Yes, that looks more realistic...and I should now be able to improve my answer...hold on.

Comment: Look I've run out of time to work on this further right now, but I promise I will do so and post an update.

Comment: Your sample data still doesn't seem consistent. The first line, the header, defines 38 comma-separated field names, but the next line of data only contains 25 comma-separated items of data. They're also not in the right order. For example by the header the seventh item should be `zipcode`, but the data value in that position in the following line is `'123 billaddr st.'` which looks like it should probably be `billaddr` which is the eighth item on the header line. Once again, please provide some realistic input data.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for my countless mistakes with formatting this csv data. There are no 38 comma-separate items of data to match the 38 comma-separated field names.

Comment: I must apologize, there are now 38 items in both the header and following data line of the sample data -- I must have missed a question update somehow along the way. Now I should be able to finish the answer update I've been working on.

Comment: I'm sorry for another one of my mistakes with the csv formatting. I removed all blanks strings '' and have just comma delimiters where no data is found

Comment: I wasn't sure if you want blank strings '' or nothing between the commas of empty data cells, so I made 2 rows of sample data. One with blank strings '' and one with nothing between the commas.

Comment: The code in my updated answer uses the version of data file with blank strings for missing items and displays `NA` for them in the output -- both of which should be easy to change. Sorry for taking so long to post the update.